# django post request: Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /categories

Tags: python, django

In my file `view.py` I want to write a class based on View with `get` and `post` methods for API. `Get` is already written, it works. There was a problem with the `post`:

Code of this class:

```
class CategoryListView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        if not check_correct_api_secret(request):
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Unknown API key')

        query_set = Category.objects.all()
        query_params = request.GET
        query_set = paginate(query_params, query_set)
        items_data = serialize_category_list(request, query_set)
        return JsonResponse(items_data, safe=False)

    # Method code is written for example, just to see some kind of reaction to the post request
    def post(self, request):
        query_params = request.POST
        name = query_params.get('name')
        Category.objects.create(name=name)

        return HttpResponse(201)
```

I try send post request: `/categories?name=Category6` (For example)
And I get error:
`Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /categories [21/Jun/2022 16:21:26] "POST /categories?name=Category777 HTTP/1.1" 403 2506`

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('categories', CategoryListView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: My request works if I delete `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from settings.py... But is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @csrf_protect in your post method.

```
@csrf_protect
    def post(self, request):
            query_params = request.POST
            name = query_params.get('name')
            Category.objects.create(name=name)
    
            return HttpResponse(201)
```

Or just to test it add
@csrf_exempt

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help

Comment: I find `requires_csrf_token` in documentation: This decorator works similarly to csrf_protect, but never rejects an incoming request. But it didn,t help too

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware.  In this case you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).